# Can a well-behaved, positive-definite function $\phi(x)$ always be represented by $\phi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mid a_{n}\psi(x)_n\mid^{2} $?

Tags: fourier-series, positive-definite

It's well known that some $\phi(x^{\mu})$
  fulfilling a basic set of criteria (on a manifold M
  of arbitrary dimension lets say dim=1 here) may be represented as a fourier series of orthogonal functions.

$$\phi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\psi_{n}(x)$$

Where the $\psi_{n}$
 's are a set of complete orthogonal basis weighted by their coefficients (the $a_{n}$
 's), which may be chosen normalized such that:

$$1=\intop_{M}\mid\psi_n\mid^{2}dx$$

(sure if we want we can take the limit as the period of $\phi(x^{\mu}$)
  goes $\rightarrow\infty$
  and make it a fourier transform in a particular case; however I'm interested in finite unbounded spaces)

This is all standard, I'm wondering about positive definite functions.

Specifically, lets say $\phi(x)$
  is positive definite, and well-behaved as above. Can we always represent
  it then in a form:

$$\phi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mid a_{n}\mid^{2}\mid\psi_n(x)\mid^{2}$$

???

I should probably add that There will be a condition such that ( I think it's pretty evident):

$$Constant=\intop_{M}\phi(x)dx$$

Comment: are you asking about [Bochner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem) in a manifold ? how do you define a [positive definite function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function) there ? why $\psi_n(x)$ squared ?

Comment: For a particular problem I'm working on, it would be immensely useful have $\phi$
  in the above form, such that I can write:

$$Constant=\int_{M}\phi(x)dx=\int_{M}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mid a_{n}\psi_{n}\mid^{2}dx$$
 

$$=<\Psi^{\dagger}(x)\Psi(x)>=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mid a_{n}\mid^{2}$$
 
where $$\Psi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\psi_{n}$$
 This would be unbelievably useful!!! also, it's interesting that we only tend to look at series expansions of a function, whereas this is the absolute value squared series expansion of a function.