# Can spherical harmonics always act as eigenfunctions?

Tags: fourier-series, eigenfunctions, spherical-harmonics

The question says it all. I can elaborate in the morning.

This is ultimately related to question [Can a well-behaved, positive-definite function $\phi(x)$ always be represented by $\phi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mid a_{n}\psi(x)_n\mid^{2} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861862/can-a-well-behaved-positive-definite-function-phix-always-be-represented-b)

I plan on using both notions in concert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spherical harmonics are eigenfunctions of the angular part of the laplace operator. and they happen to be complete and ortonormal. so a function of three variables can always be expanded as:
$$
f(x,y,z) \overset{\longrightarrow}{\textrm{sc}} f(r,\theta,\phi)=\sum_{l,m}f_{l,m}(r)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)
$$
where "sc" means a change from $(x,y,z)$ to spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$

in 3 dimensions we have:
$$
\Delta=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}-\frac{\Lambda^2}{r^2}
$$
where $\Lambda^2$ is a differential operator involving only angles.
now if we take a polynomial of G-degree with the following properties:
$$
p_G(\lambda\vec{x})=\lambda^G\, p_G(\vec{x})
$$
$$
\Delta p_G =0
$$
then one could define:
$$
Y_G(\vec{\omega})=r^{-G}p_G(\vec{x})\,\,\,\, ,\,\,\,\,|\vec{x}|=r \,\,\, , \,\,\, |\vec{\omega}|=1 
$$
if you calculate: 
$$
0=\Delta p_G=\Delta {r^G Y_G}=...=r^{G-2}\big(G(G+1)-\Lambda^2 \big)Y_G
$$
we find:
$$
\Lambda^2\, Y_G=G(G+1) Y_G
$$
so this demonstrates that an homogeneous harmonic polynomial is an eigenfunction of the angular part of the laplacian, by placing further conditions one can actually obtain the expression of a spherical harmonic.

Comment: any thoughts on the linked question? I'm pretty sure the answer's affirmative also (granted not unique)